# How to remove the redundant requests in RXJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I am working on a front-end project with Rxjs and Angular Framework and I want to get json data from a api "api/data_processor_classlib.php....". There are three parts was subscribed the pipe this.webProtectionHTML$ at HTML. I don't know why the pipe this.webProtectionHTML$ made requests 3 times. Is any possible solution that just sent one request and update all data in HTML? Thanks.

HTML Code:

```
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="align-left">Phishing & Other Frauds</div>
      <div class="align-right">{{ (webProtectionHTML$|async)?.phishing}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="align-left">Spam URLs</div>
      <div class="align-right">{{ (webProtectionHTML$|async)?.spamURLs}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="align-left">Malware Sites</div>
      <div class="align-right">{{ (webProtectionHTML$|async)?.malware}}</div>
    </div>
```

Component:

```
this.webProtectionHTML$ = this.dayService$
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((days: DaysPeriod // params added to request url) => this.httpClient.get(`api/data_processor_classlib.php....`//request url, { responseType: 'text' })),
        map((html: string) => {
          //get html code and find data return as json data
          let result = this.getWebProtectionData(html)
          return result
        }))
```

Network log:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few previous answers correctly point out that each usage of `async` pipe results in a http request - but don't explain why. In fact it's not an issue with the async pipe per se. It's because your http request observable is "cold" (as explained e.g. here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/concepts/rxjs-primer#what-is-an-observable).

"Cold" observable means it will only start doing smth and emitting values when some consumer subscribes to it. Moreover, by default each new subscription initiates new execution - even if multiple subscriptions to the same observable are created in parallel. This is exactly what you observed in your code: each async pipe subscribes to the observable separately.

There are a couple of ways to fix that.

1. Make sure you only have a single subscription. The answer by @Michael D exploits this approach. This is quite a common way to address the problem. A potential drawback is that the subscription manually created this way is not automatically unsubscribed from when the component is destroyed. In your example it might not be a big deal (if `dayService$` only emits a single value). However, if the component is destroyed before the http request has finished, this http request would not be canceled without writing some extra code (involves implementing a ngOnDestroy lifecycle method). Another drawback - you would need to manually call `changeDetector.markForCheck()`, if your component uses OnPush.
2. Make this observable "hot". "Hot" means the async action has initiated already, and all subscribers will just receive the result of that action - no matter how many subscribers there are. Using .toPromise(), as suggested by @xdeepakv, does exactly that. Note that promises are not cancellable at all - so you will have no way to cancel such a request. Another drawback - it only works if your observable emits a single value and then completes (e.g a single http request).
3. You can use `shareReplay({refCount: true})` operator to make your observable muticast - this allows multiple subscribers to share the same result. In this case you won't need to change your template, (can have multiple async pipes) and benefit from auto-unsubscribe / http request cancelation implemented in the async pipe.

```
this.webProtectionHTML$ = dayService$.pipe(
  mergeMap(...),
  map(...),
  shareReplay({refCount: true}) // <- making it a multicast
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is called three times because each `async` pipe fires a request. Instead in these cases you could subscribe in the component and use a member variable. You could then unsubscribe the subscriptions in the `ngOnDestroy` hook to avoid memory leaks. Try the following

Controller

```js
private dayServiceSubscription: Subscription;
public webProtectionHTML: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.dayServiceSubscription = this.dayService$
    .pipe(
      mergeMap((days: DaysPeriod) => this.httpClient.get(`api/data_processor_classlib.php....`//request url, { responseType: 'text' })),
      map((html: string) => this.getWebProtectionData(html)))
    .subscribe(response => this.webProtectionHTML = response);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.dayServiceSubscription) {
    this.dayServiceSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<div class="tr">
  <div class="align-left">Phishing & Other Frauds</div>
  <div class="align-right">{{ webProtectionHTML?.phishing}}</div>
</div>
<div class="tr">
  <div class="align-left">Spam URLs</div>
  <div class="align-right">{{ webProtectionHTML?.spamURLs}}</div>
</div>
<div class="tr">
  <div class="align-left">Malware Sites</div>
  <div class="align-right">{{ webProtectionHTML?.malware}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I shoudn't use async pipe.

Comment: It is actually better in most cases because it handles the memory leak issues. But one thing to remember is each `async` pipe would subscribe individually to the observable.

Comment: Yes, async pipe should subscribles an Observable individually, just like a unique thread. I am a beginner on RXJS and Angular. Your timely response is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For API, you can return as promise using `toPromise` method. It will `convert` subscribe to promise. So even you use async `3 times`. It will resolve the promise `once`.

```
this.webProtectionHTML$ = this.dayService$
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((days: DaysPeriod // params added to request url) => this.httpClient.get(`api/data_processor_classlib.php....`//request url, { responseType: 'text' })),
        map((html: string) => {
    //get html code and find data return as json data
    let result = this.getWebProtectionData(html)
          return result
        })).toPromise()
```

Answer (score 1):

It made 3 requests because the code specifies 3 async pipe for `this.webProtectionHTML$` in the template.

You got two solutions:

**1. Use single async pipe in the template**

Use `ngIf` and set async pipe with alias `as` statement in the condition

```html
<div *ngIf="webProtectionHTML$ | async as webProtection"> // define async here
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="align-left">Phishing & Other Frauds</div>
      <div class="align-right">{{ webProtection.phishing}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="align-left">Spam URLs</div>
      <div class="align-right">{{ webProtection.spamURLs}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="align-left">Malware Sites</div>
      <div class="align-right">{{ webProtection.malware}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**2. Use shareReplay() rxjs operator**
The operator is used to replay the previous data to all the subscribers. `shareReplay(1)` means that replay the last data.

```
this.webProtectionHTML$ = this.dayService$
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((days: DaysPeriod // params added to request url) => this.httpClient.get(`api/data_processor_classlib.php....`//request url, { responseType: 'text' })),
        map((html: string) => {
          //get html code and find data return as json data
          let result = this.getWebProtectionData(html)
          return result
        })),
        shareReplay(1)
```

Both works but if I can choose for this case, I like the first solution.

Hope it helps

Comment: Note that if `dayService$` can emit multiple values over time (generally, a never-ending observable), using shareReplay without refCount creates a memory leak

Answer (score 0):

Because you called it 3 times by using `(webProtectionHTML$|async)`, each time it called it and displayed the value of a different member. If you ant it to be called only once call the `this.webProtectionHTML$` in the `constructor` or `ngOnInit` and assign the returned value to a local variable that you can use its value to bind on it.